# Fatal error: Class 'models\CI_Model' not found in

Tags: codeigniter, model

Troubles getting Code Igniter to work with my model...

File 1:
user_model.php

```
class User_Model extends CI_Model {

var $idUsers;
var $Email;
var $Password;
var $CreatedAt;

function __construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
}
}
```

File 2:
autoload.php

```
$autoload['model'] = array('User_model');
```

The Error:
Fatal error: Class 'models\CI_Model' not found in /home/.../application/models/user_model.php on line 5...

The problems seems that CI_Model doesn’t exist in models, it exist in other place. system\core\Model.php

I am using CodeIgniter 2.1.4

I dont know whats wrong with this...?

Comment: `parent::_construct();` should be `parent::__construct();` (two underscores). Is this a typo?

Comment: i added the double __ but still same error.

Comment: Can you include the entire model code, or at least exactly what is on line 5 of user_model?

Comment: i already tried that and for some reason its not working i use require_once(entire_path)

Comment: Sorry, I meant post the entire model code in your question. I should have been more clear.

Answer (score 2):

your autoload is wrong

```
$autoload['model'] = array('User_model');
```

it should be

```
$autoload['model'] = array('User_Model');
```

and your constructor should be

```
parent::__construct();
```

Answer (score 2):

The name of controller and model must different.

Answer (score 0):

Your model name does not follow the [correct convention](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html#anatomy):

> Class names **must** have the first letter capitalized with the rest of the name lowercase.

So:

```
class User_Model extends CI_Model
```

should be:

```
class User_model extends CI_Model
```

Answer (score 0):

!!! **'Autoload' was having problems with some models, I did not use 'autoload'.**

First State:

[image: 1. image]
[image: Error]

**I am Solution: (I've moved, the problem has improved)**

[image: Result]